# What is the difference between URLCache.cachedResponse(for:) and URLCache.getCachedResponse(for:completionHandler:) ?

Tags: swift, nsurlcache

I am working with a server that responds with the following headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache  
last-modified: Mon, 17 Dec 2018 14:47:19 GMT
```

The following code:

```
let myTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(request: myRequest, completionHandler: { ... })  
myTask.resume()
```

correctly sends the `If-Modified-Since` header.

But when I do:

```
URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: myRequest)
```

I get a `nil` result, whereas with:

```
URLCache.shared.getCachedResponse(for: myTask, completionHandler: { ... })
```

I get a non-`nil` result in the `completionHandler`.

I would have expected both giving me similar results. Can someone explains that to me?

Answer (score 0):

This checks my local cache response.

```
if let request = dataRequest.request {
  if (URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: request) != nil) {
    URLCache.shared.removeCachedResponse(for: request)
  }
}
```

Also you can check the definition as per apple.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've read the documentation, but that does not explain the difference I observe with my example.